# Getting Resource not found error on AngularJS Route

Tags: angularjs, single-page-application

I am using AngularJS to create an SPA. I have following code in my home.ejs file:

```
/* Initial Code */
                 <li class="nav-item dropdown" >
                     <a class="nav-link dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>&nbsp; <%= sess.name.split(' ')[0] %></a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" style="margin-top:6px">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="profile">Profile</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Settings</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Logout</a>
                    </div>  
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div ng-view>

    </div>
</body>
<script>
var app = angular.module("social", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function ($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl: "home.ejs"
    })
    .when("/profile", {
        templateUrl : "/pages/profile.ejs"
    })
    .when("/settings", {
        templateUrl : "settings.ejs"
    });
});

/* Rest of the code */
```

But the problem is that this code prints the following error in the console.. :

[image: The console error is shown in the right hand side of the image]

I made sure that the file exists in the pages directory.. I am using node.js as the backend. Nothing works.. What should I do?

This is my root directory, here the profile.ejs is located inside the pages directory:

[image]

Comment: post your root directory. Otherwise try variations of `./pages/profile.ejs`,  `pages/profile.ejs`, etc.

Comment: @AlekseySolovey updated the question... I tried the variations but all yielded the same error..

Answer (score 0):

Remove the leading "/" from your path, i.e.

```
templateUrl : "pages/profile.ejs"
```

Also try hard-reloading your google chrome before testing after you make that change.